# Why does this dropdown list not update the view with the appropriate number of rows?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagedlist

I created a Helper class:

```
public class PageSizeHelper
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> ItemsPerPageList
    {
        get
        {
            return (new List<SelectListItem> {
    new SelectListItem{ Text="5", Value = "5" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="10", Value = "10", Selected = true },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="25", Value = "25"},
    new SelectListItem{ Text="50", Value = "50"},
    new SelectListItem{ Text="100", Value = "100"},
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter,int? page, int? itemsPerPage)
  {
  .
  .
  .
ViewBag.CurrentItemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
  .
  .
      int pageSize = 5;
      int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
  .
return View(data.ToPagedList(pageNumber: page ?? 1, pageSize: itemsPerPage ?? 10));
```

In the view I have:

```
@{
List<SelectListItem> itemsPerPageList = PageSizeHelper.ItemsPerPageList;
}
.
.
.
table w/ data
.
.
.
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, itemsPerPage = ViewBag.CurrentItemsPerPage, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
            <br />

@if (Model != null)
{
@Html.DropDownList("ItemsPerPage", itemsPerPageList, new { id = "ItemsPerPageList" })
}
```

I can see the correct values in the dropdown, but when I make a selection, the page isn't updated with the correct number of rows.  I know I must be doing something wrong or forgetting something.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any code that would update the page on change of that field. You'd either need some javascript, or to submit some form that reloads the page with the new list.

Comment: Kevin's right. Currently, you're just sending back `ViewBag.CurrentItemsPerPage`, not the value from the DropDownList.  You need to react to the change event of the DropDownList, capture the value, and then redirect to the action with the new `itemsPerPage`.

Comment: Thank guys! I wrapped the dropdown in a `Html.BeginForm` with `FormMethod.Post` plus I added `new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" }`to the dropdown definition, and now when you select a number from the dropdown, the page refreshes with the correct number of rows.